# Algorithm tag and page break

Tags: floats, algorithms

I'm starting my experiment with LaTeX, i'm writing an article and all that I want is to embed an algorithm inside normal text, this is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\begin{document}
\section{Lettura file .gpx} 
Lorem ipsum ...

\algsetup{indent=1.7em}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Alg capt}
\label{alg1}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
... algorithm here...
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

This is fully working but algorithmic uses a pagebreak automatically, how can I avoid this break and show the algorithm immediately after "lorem ipsum" part?

Comment: [This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351598/use-algstore-and-algrestore-many-time-for-one-algorithm) is also relevant. The answer suggests using `\algstore` and `\algrestore` for splitting the algorithm over several pages.

Answer (score 27):

Here are some suggestions:

- If you're adding your algorithm inside the `algorithm` float, then it will float according to the "float specifiers" given as the optional argument to the `algorithm` environment. For example

  ```
  \begin{algorithm}[ht]
    ...
  \end{algorithm}
  ```

To force the float to be less float-y, add `!` to the float specifier. However, as suggested by the [`float` package](//ctan.org/pkg/float), this still remains a "suggestive specifier". Instead, the package provides the additional `H` float specifier which tells LaTeX to "PUT IT HERE!"

- Use the [`algorithmx` package](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx). It is very similar to [`algorithmic`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithms), but allows for more flexibility. Here's a short, yet complete, minimal example (from the [`algorithmicx` package documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/algorithmicx)).
- If you wish to have the algorithm break across the page boundary, you have to set things up differently. I've incorporated a `breakablealgorithm` environment below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{breakablealgorithm}
  {% \begin{breakablealgorithm}
   \begin{center}
     \refstepcounter{algorithm}% New algorithm
     \hrule height.8pt depth0pt \kern2pt% \@fs@pre for \@fs@ruled
     \renewcommand{\caption}[2][\relax]{% Make a new \caption
       {\raggedright\textbf{\fname@algorithm~\thealgorithm} ##2\par}%
       \ifx\relax##1\relax % #1 is \relax
         \addcontentsline{loa}{algorithm}{\protect\numberline{\thealgorithm}##2}%
       \else % #1 is not \relax
         \addcontentsline{loa}{algorithm}{\protect\numberline{\thealgorithm}##1}%
       \fi
       \kern2pt\hrule\kern2pt
     }
  }{% \end{breakablealgorithm}
     \kern2pt\hrule\relax% \@fs@post for \@fs@ruled
   \end{center}
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listofalgorithms

\section{Some section}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{euclid}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d.\ of~$a$ and~$b$}
    \State $r \gets a \bmod b$
    \While{$r \neq 0$}\Comment{We have the answer if~$r$ is~$0$}
      \State $a \gets b$
      \State $b \gets r$
      \State $r \gets a \bmod b$
    \EndWhile
    \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The g.c.d.\ is~$b$}
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{breakablealgorithm}
  \caption{Euclid’s algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d.\ of~$a$ and~$b$}
    \State $r \gets a \bmod b$
    \While{$r \neq 0$}\Comment{We have the answer if~$r$ is~$0$}
      \State $a \gets b$
      \State $b \gets r$
      \State $r \gets a \bmod b$
    \EndWhile
    \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The g.c.d.\ is~$b$}
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{breakablealgorithm}

\end{document}
```

The above redefinition of `\caption` assumes that it will be placed where it's located in the algorithm; specifically at the top. Rule definitions were taken from the `float` package's `\@fs@ruled` construction.

Comment: Werner's answer  proposing begin{algorithm}[H] which is basically a float[H]? This means place the float 'here', however, it is still treated as a float and if Latex doesn't find enough text around it, the vertical spaces will be noticeable

Comment: @isti_spl: True. As such, it's not always advisable to use the `[H]` specifier. For more detail on the float placement algorithm, see [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/Qzz31) and [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://goo.gl/290dD).

Comment: @Werner, wow this is so beautiful. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Werner, hi, dude, your solution breakablealgorithm is great. However, i run into another problem. The label of the newly generate algorithm cannot be replaced by other language. For example, I need to replace Algorithm 1 with 算法 1 (In Chinese). I try to use command \floatname{algorithm}{算法}, but this only works for the default algorithm, not your breakablealgorithm. Any suggestions?

Comment: @sunnycomes: Right. I've updated the code to use the appropriate [`float`](//ctan.org/pkg/float)-based naming scheme.

Comment: @Werner thanks a million, you saved my life.

Comment: Thank you, it splits the algorithm perfectly! The only problem in my case is that the padding differs from the padding around regular algorithms. Is there a way to make it the same?

Comment: @LucasAschenbach: I recommend posting a [follow-up question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2117/5764) which lists the different components you're working with (like document class and packages, possibly environments also) and request an updated answer. In the very least, you should supply a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) that replicates your current setup.

Comment: @Werner Thanks, I posted a follow-up question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/695542/equal-padding-for-breakablealgorithm-environment

Comment: @Werner Replacing the center environment with `\par\vspace{\intextsep}` on both sides solved the problem for me. This is the same quantity used by the standard algorithm such that both environments will always have the same vertical padding.

Comment: THanks for `breakablealgorithm` very useful. small question: Can this work with long algorithm written using `algorithm2e` package? Or must one use `\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}`? If so, I can ask new question on this. I am currently using `algorithm2e` but need to do the same as you did here, which is have the algorithm split over more than one page.  Thought to check first.

Comment: Please ignore my question. I am switching to `algpseudocodex` and found your macro works there OK. Do not need to use `algorithm2e` for my long algorithm. So I am ok. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

If you don't want your algorithm to be treated as a floating object, then *don't* use the `algorithm` environment; you can still have a caption using the `\captionof` command from the `caption` package; using the appropriate style and format, this caption can have the same look and feel as those produced by the `algorithm` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{algor}{%
  \hrulefill\par\offinterlineskip\vskip1pt%
    \textbf{#1#2}#3\offinterlineskip\hrulefill}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{algori}{singlelinecheck=off,format=algor,labelsep=space}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{style=algori}

\begin{document}
\section{Lettura file .gpx} 
\lipsum*[1]
\begin{center}
  \captionof{algorithm}{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{euclid}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
      \State $a\gets b$
      \State $b\gets r$
      \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \EndWhile
    \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to insert a rule automatically at the end of the algorithm? I've try `\rule[15pt]{\textwidth}{0.5pt}` manually but it's so inconvenient and there will be a large gap between the rule and the following text. Thank you! @Gonzalo

Comment: @Stan, did you get a solution for the bottom line??

Comment: Note: mixing this with actual `algorithm` floats leads to duplicated horizontal ruling.

Answer (score 2):

Mine here is mainly based on Werner's amazing answer with one major fix: I grouped two top vertical lines and a caption as a page-unbreakable block using `\parbox{}`.

Below is the MME, compiled successfully with pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) on Kubuntu 20.04.2 LTS:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm, algpseudocode}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{breakablealgorithm}
{
    \begin{center}
        \refstepcounter{algorithm}
        \renewcommand{\caption}[1]
        {
            \addcontentsline{loa}{algorithm}{\protect\numberline{\thealgorithm}##1}
            \parbox{\textwidth}
            % Makes a unbreakable block and can also be done by `minipage`.
            {
                \hrule height.8pt depth0pt \kern2pt
                {\raggedright\textbf{\fname@algorithm~\thealgorithm} ##1\par}
                \kern2pt\hrule\kern2pt
            }
        }
}
{
        \kern2pt\hrule\relax
    \end{center}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \listofalgorithms

    \section{Section One}
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{breakablealgorithm}
        \caption{Euclid's algorithm}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \Procedure{Euclid}{$a, b$}
                \State $r \gets a \bmod b$
                \While{$r \not= 0$}
                    \State $a \gets b$
                    \State $b \gets r$
                    \State $r \gets a \bmod b$
                \EndWhile
                \State \textbf{return} $b$
            \EndProcedure
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{breakablealgorithm}

    \lipsum[2]
    \begin{breakablealgorithm}
        \caption{Euclid's algorithm}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \Procedure{Euclid}{$a, b$}
                \State $r \gets a \bmod b$
                \While{$r \not= 0$}
                    \State $a \gets b$
                    \State $b \gets r$
                    \State $r \gets a \bmod b$
                \EndWhile
                \State \textbf{return} $b$
            \EndProcedure
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{breakablealgorithm}
\end{document}
```

Some known issues for this code:

1. The links to `breakablealgorithm` is pointed to slightly different positions compared to the normal `algorithm` enviroment;
2. When `\caption{}` is not available (which is considered as a **VERY BAD** convention), `breakablealgorithm` will not draw two top horizontal lines since they come with `\caption{}`;
3. Figure/table floats may interrupt `breakablealgorithm`;
4. The bottom horizontal line may be placed at the top of a new page.