# Use \algstore and \algrestore many time for one algorithm

Tags: page-breaking, algorithmicx

I have an algorithm composed of three pages, can I use use `\algstore`  and `\algrestore` many times to split this algorithm on this pages?

Comment: Well, this is easy to answer: Just take any algorithm, like any example from the manual of the `algorithmicx` package, and try it.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can do this as many times as you want:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Part 1}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \If {$a>b$}
    \ForAll{x}
    \State y
    \EndFor
    \algstore{part1}
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Part 2}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \algrestore{part1}
    \Else
    \ForAll{z}
    \State t
    \EndFor
    \algstore{part2}
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Part 3}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \algrestore{part2}
    \State R
    \EndIf
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Note that it even keeps track of the line numbers, and will do this with larger increments too.

Comment: But how can I deal with the algorithm numbering (I am using the step numbering)?

Comment: The package takes care of this - I have updated the code to show this.

Comment: I really appreciate that you answered my questions, I am Latex beginner so please bear with me for this last question : if I need to divide the algorithm before the loop end, how can I handle this problem?

Comment: There is nothing special about dividing at such a point.  The commands should work as above.  In general, I would advise you to just try them on an example and see whether they work.

Comment: Sorry, I meant by a loop something like \begin{}  steps \end{}, Example : \begin{description}  steps \end{description}.

Comment: It is not usual to use description environments inside algorithms in this way.  If you need to do that, try asking a separate question and post the code for the case in question.

Comment: @ Andrew Swann, thank you very much for your answers.