# Long algorithm cannot split into two pages

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e, algorithmic

I am writing pseudo code in the algorithmic environment. It is quite long and doesn't fit on one single page. I tried with many option but cannot divide into 2 pages. In another file (since this is thesis) I declared packages for:

```
\usepackage[vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e} % Algorithm
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algcompatible}
```

Here is my code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\small

\hrule
\vspace{2mm}
\textbf{Reader Operation}
%\vspace{1mm}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]

    \STATE $ws = 1$
    \STATE FQwT([\textquoteleft 0'],$ws$); FQwT([\textquoteleft 1'],$ws$)   
    \STATE function $FQwT$(char [] $query,$ int $ws$)
    \STATE $k = ID.length$
    \STATE $L = query.length$
    \STATE $c_g=k-L$
    \STATE $s=log2(ws)$
    \STATE broadcast([$query], s$)
    \STATE $[winMatch,crcCheck] = $receiveResponses()
    \IF{$nSuccess=0$} 
    \STATE{$Phase1$}
    \IF{$isempty$($winMatch$)}
    \STATE $nIdles ++$ 
    \ELSE [$crcCheck = 0$] 
    \STATE $nCollisions ++$ 
    \IF{$ws=1$}
    \STATE $Store$ $c_g$ $with$ $query$ $into$ $LIFO$ $(c_g=k-L)$
    \STATE $FQwT$([$query$, \textquoteleft 0'],$ws$); FQwT([$query$, \textquoteleft 1'],$ws$)
    \ELSE 
    \STATE $ws = 1$
    \STATE $FQwT$ ([$query$],$ws$); FQwT([$query$],$ws$)
    \ENDIF
    \ELSE [$crcCheck=1$]
    \IF{$L + ws < k$} 
    \STATE $nGoons ++$ 
    \STATE $ws=ws ++$ 
    \STATE FQwT($[query,winMatch],ws$)
    \ELSE  [$L + ws = k$]  
    \STATE $ws=1$
    \STATE $nSuccess ++$
    \ENDIF
    \ENDIF
    \ELSE 
    \STATE{$Phase2$}
    \IF{isempty($winMatch$)}
    \STATE $nIdles ++$
    \ELSE[$crcCheck = 0$] 
    \STATE $nCollisions ++$
    \STATE FQwT([$query$, \textquoteleft 0'],$ws$); FQwT([$query$, \textquoteleft 1'],$ws$)
    \ELSE[$crcCheck = 1$]
    \IF{$L + ws < k$} 
    \STATE $nGoons ++$
    \STATE $ ws=f(c_g,L)$
    \STATE $s= log2(ws)$
    \STATE FQwT([$query$, $winMatch$],$ws$); 
    \ELSE[$L + ws = k$]  
    \STATE $nSuccess ++$
    \ENDIF
    \ENDIF
    \ENDIF

\end{algorithmic}

\vspace{1mm}
\hrule
\vspace{2mm}

\textbf{Tag Operation}
\vspace{1mm}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]

    \STATE $receive(query, s)$
    \STATE $L = query.length$
    \STATE $ws=2^s$
    \IF{$query = ID[0:L-1]$}
    \STATE $CRC=$ crc($ID[L:L{+}ws]$)
    \STATE backscatter($ID[L:L{+}ws],CRC$)
    \ENDIF

\end{algorithmic}
\vspace{1mm}
\hrule
\caption{Pseudo-code of FQwT.
    First, the operation of the reader is presented, then the tag operation.}
\label{Fig:dis53}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Floats like algorithimic cannot be broken over two pages, but environments like alagorithm can be,  See also \captionof (caption package).

Comment: @JohnKormylo what can I do?

Comment: Maybe have a look here: https://ctan.org/topic/pseudocode

Answer (score 7):

To break your algorithm over two pages, then use Werner's handy `breakablealgorithm` environment as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33869/121944).

Add this code to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{breakablealgorithm}
  {% \begin{breakablealgorithm}
   \begin{center}
     \refstepcounter{algorithm}% New algorithm
     \hrule height.8pt depth0pt \kern2pt% \@fs@pre for \@fs@ruled
     \renewcommand{\caption}[2][\relax]{% Make a new \caption
       {\raggedright\textbf{\ALG@name~\thealgorithm} ##2\par}%
       \ifx\relax##1\relax % #1 is \relax
         \addcontentsline{loa}{algorithm}{\protect\numberline{\thealgorithm}##2}%
       \else % #1 is not \relax
         \addcontentsline{loa}{algorithm}{\protect\numberline{\thealgorithm}##1}%
       \fi
       \kern2pt\hrule\kern2pt
     }
  }{% \end{breakablealgorithm}
     \kern2pt\hrule\relax% \@fs@post for \@fs@ruled
   \end{center}
  }
\makeatother
```

Then surround your `algorithmic` with `\begin{breakablealgorithm}` and `\end{breakablealgorithm}`.
Thus:

```
\begin{breakablealgorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    ...
    ...
    ...
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{breakablealgorithm}
```

**EDIT:**
If I stuff your long algorithm into Werner's environment, then it works perfectly well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode,float}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{breakablealgorithm}
  {% \begin{breakablealgorithm}
   \begin{center}
     \refstepcounter{algorithm}% New algorithm
     \hrule height.8pt depth0pt \kern2pt% \@fs@pre for \@fs@ruled
     \renewcommand{\caption}[2][\relax]{% Make a new \caption
       {\raggedright\textbf{\ALG@name~\thealgorithm} ##2\par}%
       \ifx\relax##1\relax % #1 is \relax
         \addcontentsline{loa}{algorithm}{\protect\numberline{\thealgorithm}##2}%
       \else % #1 is not \relax
         \addcontentsline{loa}{algorithm}{\protect\numberline{\thealgorithm}##1}%
       \fi
       \kern2pt\hrule\kern2pt
     }
  }{% \end{breakablealgorithm}
     \kern2pt\hrule\relax% \@fs@post for \@fs@ruled
   \end{center}
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listofalgorithms

\section{Some section}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{breakablealgorithm}
  \caption{Euclid’s algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]

    \State $ws = 1$
    \State FQwT([\textquoteleft 0'],$ws$); FQwT([\textquoteleft 1'],$ws$)   
    \State function $FQwT$(char [] $query,$ int $ws$)
    \State $k = ID.length$
    \State $L = query.length$
    \State $c_g=k-L$
    \State $s=log2(ws)$
    \State broadcast([$query], s$)
    \State $[winMatch,crcCheck] = $receiveResponses()
    \If{$nSuccess=0$} 
    \State{$Phase1$}
    \If{$isempty$($winMatch$)}
    \State $nIdles ++$ 
    \Else [$crcCheck = 0$] 
    \State $nCollisions ++$ 
    \If{$ws=1$}
    \State $Store$ $c_g$ $with$ $query$ $into$ $LIFO$ $(c_g=k-L)$
    \State $FQwT$([$query$, \textquoteleft 0'],$ws$); FQwT([$query$, \textquoteleft 1'],$ws$)
    \Else 
    \State $ws = 1$
    \State $FQwT$ ([$query$],$ws$); FQwT([$query$],$ws$)
    \EndIf
    \Else [$crcCheck=1$]
    \If{$L + ws < k$} 
    \State $nGoons ++$ 
    \State $ws=ws ++$ 
    \State FQwT($[query,winMatch],ws$)
    \Else  [$L + ws = k$]  
    \State $ws=1$
    \State $nSuccess ++$
    \EndIf
    \EndIf
    \Else 
    \State{$Phase2$}
    \If{isempty($winMatch$)}
    \State $nIdles ++$
    \Else[$crcCheck = 0$] 
    \State $nCollisions ++$
    \State FQwT([$query$, \textquoteleft 0'],$ws$); FQwT([$query$, \textquoteleft 1'],$ws$)
    \Else[$crcCheck = 1$]
    \If{$L + ws < k$} 
    \State $nGoons ++$
    \State $ ws=f(c_g,L)$
    \State $s= log2(ws)$
    \State FQwT([$query$, $winMatch$],$ws$); 
    \Else[$L + ws = k$]  
    \State $nSuccess ++$
    \EndIf
    \EndIf
    \EndIf

\end{algorithmic}
\end{breakablealgorithm}

\end{document}
```

If it works for you, all credit to Werner.

Comment: I tried and got the same :( @AML

Comment: @John988 Works for me. Try the additional code above.

Comment: I tried this and it manages to break into multiple pages, however now I can't format it using [ht] anymore.