# Float if not larger than otherwise be page-breakable

Tags: floats, page-breaking, automation

In my thesis I am embedding a few pseudocode algorithms using the `algpseudocode` and the `algorithm` packages. Thus a typical example would look like

```
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{My caption}
  \label{alg:MyAlg}

  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    ...
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

The floating behavior of the `algorithm` package is great for small-ish algorithms since it is preferrable to not have page-breaks in my algorithms and instead let the algorithm float to the next page and be inserted there.

However I also have a few larger algorithms that require more than one page in my document at which point a floating environment obviously won't work anymore since floats can't be broken across pages.

I have found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33866/128658) that provides a way of defining a breakable algorithm-like environment which works great.

However I was wondering if there was a way to have the process of deciding then to use the floating environment vs the breakable one be automated. I am thinking of a logic like "if the content is higher than x% of the current page's height, use the breakable environment and insert at the exact position it is defined in the source code but if it is smaller than that, use a floating environment".

I suppose that something like this could be made possible by grabbing the entire content, placing it in a box, getting the box's dimensions and then making the decision based on that (comparing its height to `\textheight`).

I am mainly interested in whether there already exists some sort of package that deals with this specific problem (no need to reinvent the wheel).

Comment: you could automate this but if it were my thesis, I wouldn't:  once you decide to split there are probably some places that are much better than others, if you have some nested loop you don't really want to split it one line from the end of the loop, far better to split at somewhere semantically reasonable and then force that page break to work, either having a page  a bit short or using \enlargethispage to  make it ft or whatever.

Comment: If you do want to automate it, note the float environment is already grabbing a box, and measuring the height so you would just need to patch the part where it warns the height is too large and make it unbox the content into the main vertical list.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle good point about there being places at which splitting might be less suitable than others. However I think this can only be done in the final iteration of the thesis since controlling this seems to involve explicit (manual) page-breaking which seems only a reasonable thing to do once it is sure that the contents before this part won't change (potentially moving the current algorithm to a place where the manually crafted page-break would look odd). I will certainly keep an eye on this though.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle how would patching a float in this way look like? I have to admit that I am not too familiar with box-level manipulations in TeX...

Comment: IIRC, `\begin{algorithmic} ...\end{algorithmic}` will go into a savebox, (\hbox), so you can measure the height.   `\unhbox` will not recover the contents, however.  Besides, the breakable version uses a different package with possibly different formatting.