# Use standard algorithm padding for custom algorithm environment

Tags: algorithms

> This is a follow-up question to: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33869/173478

The `breakablealgorithm` environment, as proposed by Werner, splits algorithms perfectly. However, for me the breakable algorithms have different vertical padding from the regular algorithms. The following is a minimal example for reproducing the behavior:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{breakablealgorithm}
  {% \begin{breakablealgorithm}
   \begin{center}
     \refstepcounter{algorithm}% New algorithm
     \hrule height.8pt depth0pt \kern2pt% \@fs@pre for \@fs@ruled
     \renewcommand{\caption}[2][\relax]{% Make a new \caption
       {\raggedright\textbf{\fname@algorithm~\thealgorithm} ##2\par}%
       \ifx\relax##1\relax % #1 is \relax
         \addcontentsline{loa}{algorithm}{\protect\numberline{\thealgorithm}##2}%
       \else % #1 is not \relax
         \addcontentsline{loa}{algorithm}{\protect\numberline{\thealgorithm}##1}%
       \fi
       \kern2pt\hrule\kern2pt
     }
  }{% \end{breakablealgorithm}
     \kern2pt\hrule\relax% \@fs@post for \@fs@ruled
   \end{center}
  }
\makeatother

% DOCUMENT

\begin{document}

This is some text.
\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \caption{Regular Algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}
    \State Start
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
And some more text.
\begin{breakablealgorithm}
  \caption{Breakable Algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}
    \State Start
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{breakablealgorithm}
And even more text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, when setting the document class to amsart or amsbook, there is no padding at all. How can I modify the `breakablealgorithm` environment to naturally have the same padding as the regular algorithm environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the `algorithm` environment is using the `\intextsep` quantity for vertical padding. The `breakablealgorithm` environment can therefore be modified to always have the same padding as the `algorithm` environment by replacing the `center` environment with the appropriate vertical spacing:

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{breakablealgorithm}
  {% \begin{breakablealgorithm}
    \par\vspace{\intextsep}
      \refstepcounter{algorithm}% New algorithm
      \hrule height.8pt depth0pt \kern2pt% \@fs@pre for \@fs@ruled
      \renewcommand{\caption}[2][\relax]{% Make a new \caption
        {\raggedright\textbf{\fname@algorithm~\thealgorithm} ##2\par}%
        \ifx\relax##1\relax % #1 is \relax
          \addcontentsline{loa}{algorithm}{\protect\numberline{\thealgorithm}##2}%
        \else % #1 is not \relax
          \addcontentsline{loa}{algorithm}{\protect\numberline{\thealgorithm}##1}%
        \fi
        \kern2pt\hrule\kern2pt
     }
  }{% \end{breakablealgorithm}
      \kern2pt\hrule\relax% \@fs@post for \@fs@ruled
    \par\vspace{\intextsep}
  }
\makeatother
```