# Pretty print a long algorithm that overflows to the next page

Tags: tcolorbox, algorithmicx, algpseudocode, algpseudocodex

I've been trying to pretty print an algorithm that is quite long and overlaps to the next page.

I could manage that with `algpsudocodex` and [breakablealgorithm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33866/algorithm-tag-and-page-break), but I do not like the looks.

With `tcolorbox` I can make an algorithm environment that looks pretty.  But it does not overflows to the next page, even with the `breakable` option.

My minimal example has three pages.  Algorithm 1 is a `breakablealgorithm` and overlaps properly to page 2.  Page 3 has my own `tcbalgorithm` (combining `breakablealgorithm`and `tcolorbox`), but if I increase the `\vspace{16cm}` to `\vspace{17cm}` in the source code, the whole algorithm will jump to page 4.

Is there away to combine both somehow, and have the `tcbalgorithm` behave as `breakablealgorithm`?

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocodex}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{breakablealgorithm}
  {% \begin{breakablealgorithm}
   \begin{center}
     \refstepcounter{algorithm}% New algorithm
     \hrule height.8pt depth0pt \kern2pt% \@fs@pre for \@fs@ruled
     \renewcommand{\caption}[2][\relax]{% Make a new \caption
       {\raggedright\textbf{\fname@algorithm~\thealgorithm} ##2\par}%
       \ifx\relax##1\relax % #1 is \relax
         \addcontentsline{loa}{algorithm}{\protect\numberline{\thealgorithm}##2}%
       \else % #1 is not \relax
         \addcontentsline{loa}{algorithm}{\protect\numberline{\thealgorithm}##1}%
       \fi
       \kern2pt\hrule\kern2pt
     }
  }{% \end{breakablealgorithm}
     \kern2pt\hrule\relax% \@fs@post for \@fs@ruled
   \end{center}
  }

\newif\iftkcaption
\newenvironment{tcbalgorithm}[1][]
  {% \begin{breakablealgorithm}
  \tkcaptiontrue
   \begin{center}
     \refstepcounter{algorithm}% New algorithm
     \ifx\relax#1\relax
         \begin{tcolorbox}
     \else
         \addcontentsline{loa}{algorithm}{\protect\numberline{\thealgorithm}#1}%
         \begin{tcolorbox}[title={\textbf{\fname@algorithm~\thealgorithm} #1}]
     \fi
  }{% \end{breakablealgorithm}
     \end{tcolorbox}
   \end{center}
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Top of page
\vspace*{18.5cm}
\begin{breakablealgorithm}
  \caption{This algorithm crosses page boundaries}
  \label{alg:bk}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State This algorithm has four lines and overflows to the next page
    \State This is line two
    \State This is line three
    \State This is line four
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{breakablealgorithm}  

Referencing Algorithm~\ref{alg:bk}.

\newpage
Top of page

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\vspace{16cm} % replace with 17cm and the colored box will move to the next page
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{tcbalgorithm}[This algorithm does not cross page boundaries]
  \label{alg:tk}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State Replace the \verb!\vspace{16cm}! above with \verb!\vspace{17cm}! 
    \State and this box will move to the next page
    \State This is line three
    \State This is line four
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{tcbalgorithm}  

Referencing Algorithm~\ref{alg:tk}.

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You load the `breakable` library in package option.  However you still need to add `breakable` option to tcolorbox.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comment, you didn't add `breakable` option to the `tcolorbox` definition.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocodex}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{tcbalgorithm}[1][]
  {%
  \refstepcounter{algorithm}% New algorithm
     \ifx\relax#1\relax
         \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
     \else
         \addcontentsline{loa}{algorithm}{\protect\numberline{\thealgorithm}#1}%
         \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,title={\textbf{\fname@algorithm~\thealgorithm} #1}]
     \fi
  }{%
  \end{tcolorbox}
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listofalgorithms\clearpage
Top of page
\vspace{17.5cm}

\begin{tcbalgorithm}[This algorithm does not cross page boundaries]
  \label{alg:tk}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State Replace the \verb!\vspace{16cm}! above with \verb!\vspace{17cm}! 
    \State and this box will move to the next page
    \State This is line three
    \State This is line four
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{tcbalgorithm}  

Referencing Algorithm~\ref{alg:tk}.
\vspace{16.5cm}

\begin{tcbalgorithm}
  \label{alg:tk2}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State Replace the \verb!\vspace{16cm}! above with \verb!\vspace{17cm}! 
    \State and this box will move to the next page
    \State This is line three
    \State This is line four
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{tcbalgorithm}  

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Silly me!  Thank you!